# Why is a "jack" called "un gato"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, animales, polisemia, construcción-y-obra

### Español

¿Por qué se llama "gato" a un "jack"? Esto es, el gato hidráulico o mecánico que se usa para levantar grandes pesos.

Para mí, un "jack" no se parece para nada al animal "gato".

---

### English

Why is a "jack" called "un gato" in Spanish? A "jack" does not look like a cat to me, so where is the connection?

Comment: @fedorqui creo que Clay se está refiriendo a los gatos hidráulicos, los que se usan para levantar coches. Clay, BTW, what's so crow-y about a crowbar? It clearly is goat-y: una pata de cabra (I'm just joking).

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because I read it in an unsourced Y!Answers thread, but I liked it and it's quite recurrent: apparently they did resemble a cat arching its spine when they used to be made with a rhombus shape (plus the lever for erected tail). Another Y! theory is stray cats' tendency to look for shelter under cars.

Comment: ... and it could get more confusing. There are: "gato" "gato botella" "gato caimán (Venezuela)" "gato zorra (Colombia)" "Crique Macaco (Argentina)" and I think there are more animal names for this tool.

Comment: En Chile es _gata_, femenino.

Comment: Very good question. Always had the same doubt. In translated films to Spanish they use the word "gato", but in Peru they call it "gata". Here's the formal definition in the DRAE (Number 5)  http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0VULIX|J0X0PpO|J0XH87J      But sadly, this doesn't explain the origin of the word!!!!

Comment: @Rodrigo que bueno saber que no sólo en Perú le llaman "gata".

Comment: This strikes me as an odd question, given that in English "jack" has multiple, completely unrelated, meanings as well.

Comment: Siempre me pareció que la palabra provenía de la ubicación de la herramienta: justo debajo del vehículo, el lugar preferido de los gatos. (I made this comment into an answer too)

Answer (score 15):

To complement what was said by guillem and Carlos Alejo, there are several other cases in which we give animal's name to the tools and vice versa, depending on some physical resemblance, as a metaphor.

I give you a list of others that come to my mind, sorry if they are Chilean regionalisms, probably in other countries use other names:

> **caimán** (alligator): in Chile locking pliers. In Colombia, Venezuela: jaw hair clip
>
> **perro** (dog): clothespin
>
> **laucha** (a small rodent): **fish** tape
>
> **yegua** (mare): hand truck
>
> **mula** (mule): in Chile forklift, in Colombia 18 wheeler truck
>
> **mariposa** (butterfly): wing nut
>
> **ratón**: **mouse** (plugged into my PC)
>
> **tiburón** (shark): jaw hair clip
>
> **pata de cabra** (goat's paw): **crow** bar
>
> **pico de loro** (parrot's beak): tongue-and-groove pliers
>
> **pico de pato** (duck's beak) : pipe wrench

... And I add other examples given in the comments:

> **zorra** (female fox) in Colombia: hand truck (thanks DGaleano)
>
> **pulpo** (octopus): luggage strap (thanks guillem, this and next 3))
>
> **ojo de buey** (bull's eye): porthole
>
> **ojo de pez**: fisheye
>
> **[grifo](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-llamar-grifo-a-la-llave-de-paso-del-agua/)** (griffin): faucet
>
> **perico** (parrot): in Mexico adjustable wrenches (thanks J A Terroba)
>
> **[loro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NceUIet%7CNcixjba)** (parrot): radiocasete (thanks fedorqui)

Comment: Muchas gracias, Rodrigo; nunca he oi "jaw hair clip" - estoy casi estremecedora veo a una.

Comment: Is not a tool, it is a hair accessory. The translation is from Google

Comment: I'm enjoying this question. We don't have an answer but we are learning fun things which for me is the point of this site. BTW Some are different In Colombia...  Mula=18 wheeler truck, Fish tape = Cinta de pesca (used by electricians). Hand truck=zorra.  Locking pliers = "Hombresolo"

Comment: @Rodrigo: ya entiendo; aun tengo miedo de veo algo asi.

Comment: Some more: pulpo (luggage strap), ojo de buey (porthole), ojo de pez (same as in English)... And the most ubiquitous of them all: ratón (same as in English), and [grifo](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-llamar-grifo-a-la-llave-de-paso-del-agua/) (faucet)!

Comment: In Mexico, adjustable wrenches are called "perico" lit. parrot.

Comment: Al radiocasete también se le llama _[loro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NceUIet|Ncixjba)_.

Comment: @Rodrigo, _Solo he oído_ que `caimán` es el equivalente de  `jaw hair clip`, pero no `tiburón`. Si se puede expandir la respuesta, si hablas del `equipo tiburón` puede entenderse como referencia al equipo de fútbol [Junior de Barranquilla](https://www.google.com.co/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=equipo+tibur%C3%B3n+colombia)

Comment: At least in Argentina, wire "alligator clips" are _cocodrilos_ (could also be the hair clips), and _perros_ is sometimes used for the wires used to pass charge from one car to another (battery jumpers?). _Mosquito_ for the car-carrying trucks. _Papagayo_ is the male urinal used in hospitals (a bottle with a twisted wide neck). The list keeps going...

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to say that this also happens in English. See this article from [google.com/newspapers](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=22&dat=19160507&id=VNQDAAAAIBAJ&sjid=4igDAAAAIBAJ&pg=5022,3136247&hl=en) about *tools with animal names*.

> #### Tools with Animal Names
>
> Have you ever realized what a number of appliances have been named
>   after animals? asks Answers. And can you furnish an explanation?
>
> A mechanic puts his work upon a horse, or buck, and he punches it or
>   bends it by a convenient bear. Hoisting is done by a crab, a
>   convenient cat is part of the outfit of a shop crane, and a kit of
>   tools is ever at hand.
>
> A crow helps to straighten work, a jack to lift it; a mule pulley
>   helps to drive machinery which a donkey engine turns. A fish connects
>   parts end to end, shells are used all over, while a worm does quiet
>   but powerful work.
>
> Again, a cock shuts off the water; a ram lifts it. A printing press
>   has a fly, the first locomotive had a grasshopper valve motion, and
>   butterfly valves are common.
>
> Herring bone gears are used by the best builders; turtles fit printing
>   press cylinders, and flywheels are running all over the world.

Also a guess, it could be that some tools resemble animals such as alligator clips, resembling an alligator jaw, and crowbars and crow foot wrenches, resembling a crow's foot. Then it became commonplace to name tools after animals, regardless of similarities.

Answer (score 5):

At first I thought that it was just another case of [polysemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy), a word with two unrelated meanings, but then I investigated further...

It seems that in the 18th century the word *gato* and its derived word *gatillo* were already used as words for any kind of curved instruments. So we have, according to the *Diccionario de Autoridades* from 1734:

> GATO. Significa también cierto instrumento que sirve para agarrar y asir fuertemente la madera, y hacerla venir al término que se pretende.
>   GATO. Se llama asímismo un instrumento que consta de tres garfios de acero, y sirve para reconocer y examinar el alma de los cañones y piezas de artillería.
>   GATO. En la Náutica es un instrumento de madera que tiene dentro un tornillo grueso de hierro, con el cual se levanta cualquier cosa por pesada que sea.

Note that this last description coincides with the current knowledge of what a jack is. Also, you can see the following descriptions for *gatillo* (a diminutive form for *gato*):

> GATILLO. Se llama también cierto instrumento de hierro a modo de tenaza, con que se sacar las muelas y dientes.
>   GATILLO. Se llama asímismo en los arcabuces y demás armas de fuego, el hierro que sostiene la llave, y retirado con el movimiento, cae con violencia, y herido el pedernal del rastrillo, con la chispa se enciende la pólvora y sale el tiro.

The second meaning describes a *trigger*, and the first one a device to extract teeth. I've seen in some texts that this device could be made in the same form as a nutcracker, with curved ends. And a *trigger* is also curved.

So, any device with a curved form, including the way a jack *curves* itself, seems to have been designated after the way a cat curves its back. I'm looking for a text that confirmes this point, but I haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the name is possibly due to the similarity in form between the tool and a cat arching its back:

> El movimiento característico que ejecuta el gato cuando arquea el lomo puede haber dado origen a que, en Chile, se denominara gata 'una herramienta giratoria para levantar grandes pesos a poca altura', máquina que en España se llama gato.
>
> - [*Boletín de filología*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GPpYAAAAMAAJ&q=%22gato%22+%22herramienta%22), Volumes 18-19 (p.255) (1966)

Answer (score 2):

### in Spanish the name of the tool (*gato*) seems to be based off on a direct analogy with cats, which usually sit underneath cars, right where jacks are used.

[image: cat sitting beneath car just where jacks work]

I always thought it made a lot of sense for it to be a metaphorical link between the two.  It is easy to observe how these animals are frecuently found sitting below vehicles, seeking shelter and comfort there. The proximity to the engines keep them warm and protected from sight. [See this source](https://www.seniorcatwellness.com/how-to-get-a-cat-out-from-under-a-car/)

> Why do cats hide underneath cars? The top of wheels and underside of cars are interesting places to a cat. They provide warmth and security. The likelihood of a cat sheltering under a car is magnified when you live in a neighborhood of multiple vehicle ownership and areas where people tend to park their cars outside.

I also searched for the soundness of this and found [the same explanation](https://jobin.es/blog/origen-palabras-reparacion/) about the probable origin of the tool's name being a metaphor of a cat.

> *Lo que conocemos como GATO, esa herramienta dedicada al elevamiento de cargas, se cree que está relacionada, efectivamente, con el mamífero del cual toma su nombre. Se trataría de una metáfora acerca de la manera de esconderse de los gatos debajo de las cosas, dejando solo su cola a la vista. De esta misma manera, de la herramienta solo vemos la palanca cuando se encuentra debajo de un coche.*

Translated:

> What we know as a *GATO* [Spanish for "jack"], the tool used to lift heavy loads, is believed to be related to the mammal from which it takes its name [*gato* is also Spanish for "cat"]. It'd be a simile on how cats hide under things, leaving only their tails on sight. Likewise, the tool's lever is the only thing we see when it's put under a car.

Answer (score 1):

La palabra gato es una palabra polisémica. Significa que es una palabra que significa cosas diferentes.

*Gato* es un animal y también es una herramienta para la elevación de autos; como es el caso de la palabra *Gato hidráulico*.

Answer (score 0):

The similarity is found within the act of "climbing". In one mechanical jack design,
up and down motion is obtained by means of interlocking gears. Like a cat scaling a pole,a "gato" climbs a toothed metal support to lift the load.

Comment: Maybe "tree" would be even better than "pole." This makes intuitive sense to me, and it hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

## Named after the reversing latch

Early jacks looked much different from today's devices:

[image: Leonardo da Vinci] Leonardo da Vinci

[image: farm jack] A farm jack

These early (farm) jacks always incorporated a **reversing latch,** or at least a blocking latch. Because of its curved shape and in analogy to a pistol/gun trigger, this part is called ***gatillo*** in Spanish.

[image: reversing latch] The silver coloured reversing latch of a farm jack.

[image: labelled parts]

*Gatillo* is the diminutive of [***el gato,*** a cannon inspection device](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gato_(ca%C3%B1%C3%B3n)) that **resembled the open paws of a cat.** At about the same time, cannons and pistols started to have triggers. These had a similar curved shape as the fingers of *el gato,* the cannon inspection device. This is how the term *gatillo* came about for round shaped triggers and latches.
See also: [*CAÑÓN NAVAL: DEFINICIÓN, PARTES Y UTENSILIOS.*](https://www.artillerianaval.es/canon-naval/)

[image: El gato]

The funny thing is that the word for "jack" went back to the (bigger) base word ***gato,*** after having passed over the diminutive ***gatillo*** for curved latches and pistol triggers.

In [*CAÑÓN NAVAL: DEFINICIÓN, PARTES Y UTENSILIOS.*](https://www.artillerianaval.es/canon-naval/) the word ***gato*** is also already used to denominate a cannon jack.
This may have lead to some confusion to which *gato* was meant, although I suspect both *gato* devices were employed simultaneously. I am not a cannon maintenance expert though, nor ***armador***.